# How do I beat Dracul puzzle #2: Restless Dead?

Tags: desktop-dungeons

I'm stuck on the 2nd puzzle of the Fresh Blood puzzle pack (the ones dealing with the god Dracul), titled *Restless Dead*.

[image]

I can't seem to get enough damage to kill the dragon and win the puzzle. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you're looking for is a hint, solving this puzzle requires both an understanding on how the Burning property on the fireball works, and understanding how strike order works and the fact that you get first strike on creatures that are lower level than you.

Getting more in-depth, you need to nearly kill the wraith with fireballs, getting two stacks of burning on it. Then you attack the dragon to trigger burning, which finishes off the wraith (which you get 4xp for, since we're still level 1). Then you use Blood Curse on Dracul's altar to become level 2 so that you can first strike the goat (which would otherwise kill you, since you only have 1 health left). This will level you, refreshing health and mana, and allow you to finish off the dragon.

Finally, here is the step-by-step:

1. Fireball the wraith.
2. Drink you mana potion.
3. Fireball the wraith. Note it has 2 health left, which *burning* will take care of in step 5.
4. Convert the health potion so that you don't drop below 0 piety when the wraith dies.
5. Attack the dragon (burning kills the wraith at this point).
6. Use Blood Curse at Dracul's altar to become level 2, allowing you to get first strike on goat.
7. Kill the goat, which levels you up.
8. Fireball the dragon.
9. Convert the fireball glyph for attack power (if you don't do this, you'll end up short on damage).
10. Attack the dragon twice.
11. Blood Swell at Dracul's altar to fully heal.
12. Attack the dragon twice more to kill it.